# smbus library is not found in MicroPython using esp32

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

I want to program max30100 in my esp32 using python, I have the max30100 library https://github.com/mfitzp/max30100. The problem is, it requires smbus I tried to install smbus using the Thonny Plugin manager but it causes an error.

I just want to program max30100 in esp32 using python but this thing is delaying me.
Is there any way to use this library (max30100) without compiling smbus?
Or is there other way to use max30100 module using python in esp32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea could be following- do not use SMBUS lib.

This max30100 library can be used with I2C or SMBUS. You may try to comment out `import smbus`

Also, some changes are needed in library file itself. There are lines in library

```
# Default to the standard I2C bus on Pi.
self.i2c = i2c if i2c else smbus.SMBus(1)
```

So you may try to change these to `self.i2c = i2c` and try to use max30100 library from your code.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've tried it and guess what! I just found our that the sensor I bought is defective, I have to and both of them are :( I bought a new one which is max30100/30102 which is a revision of max30100 the defective one.